# Status code 401 at swift about authentication issue

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, alamofire

all 
I can't authenticate on my webserver by swift.
I can authenticate on my webserver by Postman.

this is postman
[image]

this is my swift.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
        let authLoginUrl = "http://ec2-52-79-171-171.ap-northeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8000/rest-auth/login/"
        let keychain = Keychain(service: "wanote")
        let tokenUse = "Token 869463aacc84f0fb9edfb251fa73b352fc52a4d5"
        let projectUrl = "http://ec2-52-79-171-171.ap-northeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8000/api/user/ryulstory"
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
            if let Purl = URL(string: self.projectUrl){
                var mutableUrlRequest = URLRequest(url: Purl)
                mutableUrlRequest.setValue(self.tokenUse, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
                mutableUrlRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
                _ = Alamofire.SessionManager.default.request(mutableUrlRequest)
                    .responseJSON{ response in
                        print(response.request)
                        print(response.response)
                        print(response.data)
                        print(response.result)
            }
        }
    }
        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }


    }
```

I think the setvalue is maybe wrong. could you teach me what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In `mutableUrlRequest.setValue(self.tokenUse, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")`, your `self.tokenUse` should be your clientID. If it's correct, why your `tokenUse` has "Token " prefix?

Try this

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
    "Authorization": self.tokenUse,
    "Accept": "application/json"
]

Alamofire.request("http://ec2-52-79-171-171.ap-northeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8000/api/user/ryulstory", headers: headers).responseJSON { response in

    debugPrint(response)
}
```

Comment: I think that forHTTPheaderField is same as key(Authorization) and self.tokenUse is same as value on Postman. so in value in postman it need Token Prefix.

Comment: As you use Alamofire, can you try again with my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you insert `App Transport Security`and `Allow Arbitrary Loads` to `YES`? Into your `Info.plist`? This plist modification allows Apple transport security rules to let request with `200` HTTP servers.